# What is the proper way to add newlines to text email?

Tags: email, text, newline

Proper means works on different platforms (MAC/PC/Unix) and software (Outlook, Thunderbird, GMail, etc.).

Is it `\n` or `\r\n` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emails conform to the MIME specification, but even with the original SMTP RFC the situation was the same: the specification clearly states that line breaks must be represented by a CR LF sequence. This is not platform dependent, email text is not the same as a text file. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-4.1.1

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately Gmail doesn't display them.

Comment: @BSeven I have no problem with gmail displaying line breaks. What is the source of your message?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately since you want it to be cross-platform, it depends on the email client. Almost all modern email clients can handle either format. I would stick with  and confirm if all windoze based clients can handle those (they should be able to).